# How to display Data in popup modal without using for loop?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to display data in the popup, I have a list on products but when a user clicks on the `product id` then it should be open in popup according to that product `id`.

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def myview(request):
   datas=TestForm.objects.all
   template_name='test.html'
   context={'datas':datas}
   return render(request, template_name, context)

def myview(request, id):
   display=TestForm.objects.get(pk=id)
   template_name='test.html'
   context={'display':display}
   return render(request, template_name, context)
```

here is my `test.html` file...

```
{% for a in datas %}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" class="open-modal" data-url="{% url 'myap:list_single' a.id %}" data-toggle="modal" data- 
  target="#exampleModal">
  {{a.product_id}}
   </button>
  {% endfor %}

 <!-- Modal -->
<div class="extra-div">
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
  labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
 </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
   <tr>
    <td>{{datas.name}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.price}}</td>
    <td>{{datas.category}}</td>
   </tr>
 </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
 </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

here is my `jquery` which I am writing to display popup according to product id..

```
var modalDiv = $(".extra-div");
  $(".open-modal").on("click", function(){
  $.ajax({
  url: $(this).attr("data-url")
  success: function(data) {
   modalDiv.html(data);
  $("#exampleModal").modal("show");
   }
  });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery.load() method to fetch product data from server instead of pre-rendering all that popups in template

```
<script>
    $("#your_popup_div").load("/your_product_id_view_url", {'id': 1})
</script>
```